# How to put overall distribution boxplot along side grouped boxplots in R

Tags: r, boxplot

To make multiple boxplots of column "xcolumn" based on a group, I can simply do:

```
boxplot(xcolumn ~ group, data = df)
```

And to plot the overall distribution:

```
boxplot(df$xcolumn)
```

But, is it possible to have the overall distribution of xcolumn in the same plot with the grouped boxplot? I want to have the overall distribution  as the first boxplot, followed by boxplots from each group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just duplicate the values and give them a new name, say "tot", and `rbind()` it together. Use `relevel()` to move the new factor level to the front.

```
set.seed(1)
dtf <- data.frame(g=rep(c("A", "B"), 12), a=rnorm(24)+(2:1))
tot <- dtf
tot$g <- "tot"

dtf.tot <- rbind(dtf, tot)
dtf.tot$g <- relevel(dtf.tot$g, "tot")

boxplot(a ~ g, data=dtf.tot)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can add a new column for the overall group, then use `ggplot`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

iris %>% 
  mutate(Group = "all") %>% 
  ggplot() + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(Species, Sepal.Length)) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(Group, Sepal.Length))
```

[image]